# How to add Two listview in one listview into the pageview builder flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I used two listView inside listview,when i put the overall listview inside the pageview, the pageview is not scrolable

Comment: share your some code, what you have done until now?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Listviews inside each other, I suggest you to use a `GridView`. I think your `ListView`s have different directions. If they do, `GridView`s will  help you.

Other solution, if you insist on using `ListView`, then wrap the `ListView`s with `ConstrainedBox` then give them `BoxConstraints`

```
ConstrainedBox(
  constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: 100, maxWidth: 200)
  child: ListView(),
)
```

You should adjust `maxHeight` and `maxWidth` in the proper size.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you are looking for sliverlist

[SliverList & SliverGrid](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ORiTTaVY6mM)

or sliver tool

[sliver_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/sliver_tools)